# "Subclassing" a type in Haskell

Tags: haskell, subclassing

I have a data type called `Process`, which is a parameter to various functions. But not all Processes are alike. There are different types of Proccesses, which all have something in common, but differ in other aspects. My question is: what idioms do I have available to model this.

What I tried so far:

**1st attempt**

Capture the specifics of a Process in a `run` function inside the Process datatype. The Type of the run function would be the same for all Processes, but its implementation may differ between Processes of different types. I abanoned this idea, because I cannot look inside the `run` function from outside, i.e. I cannot modify it. I cannot alter specific aspects of it, I only can provide an entirely new run function. An operation like *start 10 minutes* later would be impossible to implement.

**2nd attempt** Use multiple constructors

```
type PlaceDep = Int
type PlaceArr = Int
type DepartureTime = Int
type Speed = Int

data Process = Train      PlaceDep PlaceArr DepartureTime
             | MovingBelt PlaceDep PlaceArr Speed
     deriving (Eq, Show)

prc1 = Train      10 11 1
prc2 = MovingBelt 12 13 2
```

Here it bugs me that the fact that all Processes have PlaceDep and PlaceArr seems a bit coincidental and is not expressed celarly

**3rd attempt** Use one constructor but add `ProcessParameters` having multiple constructors

```
type PlaceDep = Int
type PlaceArr = Int

data ProcessParams = DepartureTime Int | Speed Int
                   deriving (Eq, Show)
data Process = Process PlaceDep PlaceArr ProcessParams
                   deriving (Eq, Show)

prc1 = Process   10 11 (DepartureTime 1)
prc2 = Process   12 13 (Speed 2)
```

This looks promising so far. In any case I am interested to hear about other possible options.

**Note**

The question was edited multiple times. Some comments and answers may refer to older versions.

Comment: Some code samples showing your intent would probably help (even if they don't work)

Comment: To make @Daenyth's suggestion more firmly put, I have no idea what you're talking about unless you show me, and I certainly can't give an answer. Please post some code, maybe scaled down a bit.

Comment: You may benefit greatly by thinking of `Process` as a monad, additionally.

Comment: What is similar about processes, and what is different about them? Why would you use different ones? Maybe you want an ADT, a GADT, a typeclass, a record of functions, or something else. Without knowing what it's *for*, it's hard to advise.

Comment: @AJFarmer I made a monad for the decisions a Process has to make in order to compute what it'll do next. That looks promising so far. But as for Processes themselves I have no clear idea about what "chaining processes" could possibly mean, unless it is a simple pipeline.

Comment: This still isn't concrete enough. Can you show some pseudo-code for something fairly realistically close to what you actually want to do?

Comment: @MartinDrautzburg Then why not a simple pipeline? That's a monad if ever I heard of one!

Comment: @AJFarmer: because I have splits and merges, i.e. Processes with more than one input and more than one output. I could try to do something like the arrow combinators, but currently I am shying away from this.

Comment: @MartinDrautzburg Then you're describing a preexisting monad: [condiuts](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit).

Comment: @AIFarmar, do conduits really support that?

Comment: Before I look at conduits, let me ask you one questions: a fundametal constraint of my Processes is that you cannot move an item to a place where there is no room. I had high hopes in arrows, but found that they are not suitable for this kind of problem ("backwater effect"). Are conduits any better in this respect?

Comment: @AJFarmer I was a bit quick with my monad scepticism. I will try and think along the lines of Process a b where Process a describes what all Processes do and b captures the specifics. I'll have to sleep over it.

Comment: @MartinDrautzburg I would urge you to look at conduits, they certainly surprised me in their capabilities.

Comment: You may also want to look at `machines`.

Comment: "An operation like start 10 minutes later would be impossible to implement." Represent your process as an ADT like : `data Process a = Delay Float (Process a) | Atom a`. The atoms are whatever you like; and the ADT only has to encode structure you are actually interested in.

Answer (score 3):

As, I'm sure, you know, there is no inheritance in Haskell. However it is not a problem at all. Cases like yours can easily be solved with a scalable approach called "Composition", which lately gets preferred over "Inheritance" even in OO languages.

What you need to do is implement each "Process" in isolation in separate modules and then in another module have a dome interface around a type, which is composed from all of them. That type is likely to be a union of those specific types of processes, while functions in it will mostly be about routing to functions of specific implementations. E.g.:

```
module MoreGeneralProcess where

import qualified SpecificProcess1
import qualified SpecificProcess2


data Process = SpecificProcess1 SpecificProcess1.Process |
               SpecificProcess2 SpecificProcess2.Process

doOneGeneralThing :: Process -> IO ()
doOneGeneralThing process =
  case process of
    SpecificProcess1 x -> SpecificProcess1.doOneGeneralThing x
    SpecificProcess2 x -> SpecificProcess2.doOneGeneralThing x
```

This is a common and infinitely scalable pattern. [In some Haskell dialects it is even an idiom](https://github.com/evancz/elm-architecture-tutorial/#example-2-a-pair-of-counters).

Comment: This example does not cater for the common parts. If I add them, I end up with my ProcessParams, I believe. Maybe this is just the best solution.

Comment: You just need to think a little differently here. The general API is exactly supposed to handle the common parts and them only. The functions in it are supposed to be mainly about routing to functions of specific modules. Thus you get a clear and infinitely scalable architecture. Otherwise, if you two specific things, which happen to share a few aspects, as a single entity, you're likely to get a code spaghetti.

Comment: I still cannot quite see it. Suppose all Processes have a name. A function which returns a copy of a Process but with a different name ("rename")  would not have to know about the specifics. You seem to suggest having a "rename" function in SpecificProcess1 and SpecificProcess2.

Comment: No. I suggest to think the reverse way. First implement the specific processes in isolation without thinking of sibling processes or the general one. Then construct the general one using their APIs. If you can't implement the "rename" function, then there's only two possible reasons for that: either it should be partial (e.g., return something like `Maybe`) or it doesn't make sense for the general API at all. After all, what's the point in making a general API, which does not generalize anything?

Comment: I believe I understand now. The specific Processes do not necessarily need a "rename" operation, but something which allows constructing a "rename" function from it, right? Shouldn't SpecificProcess1.doOneGeneralThing in your case expression rather be SpecificProcess1.doOneThing as the specific process does not know whether it is doing something specific or general?

Comment: Yes, if that helps, the names of functions of specific modules don't matter at all. See my post concerning composition: http://nikita-volkov.github.io/haskells-modules-system-has-problems-with-composition/